# How I can navigate to another page from a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am new at the area of Objective-C and am building an iphone app using Xcode. I have taken two buttons on a page and from among one I would like to go to another page. How is it possible at Xcode?

Comment: what do you mean by page? is it UIScrollView or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
EnterNameController *newEnterNameController = [[EnterNameController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EnterNibFileName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EnterNameController *newEnterNameController = [[EnterNameController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"EnterNibFileName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController animated:YES];
[newEnterNamecontroller release];
```

This one is more accurate as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is a basic building block of iPhone apps, and Apple provides plenty of sample code that shows how to do it.

Start by looking at the UICatalog sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Get the book ["Beginning iPhone Development"](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430216263) and go through it from start to finish without skipping anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
TwoViewController * twoVC = [[TwoViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:twoVC animated:YES];
```

"TwoViewController" is a custom UIViewController